# PostgreSQL 8.2 extract week number from a a date field

Tags: postgresql, date, postgresql-8.2

This might be a simple one but I haven't got a solution yet. I have a create_date field which is a date type, and a revenue number. I want to see weekly break down of revenue.

I can get the numbers easily in tableau because of built in functionality but doing it in PostgreSQL is where I need some help.

Comment: Like in `SELECT EXTRACT(week FROM datecolumn)`?. You can also filter on [`EXTRACT()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-datetime.html) but mind your indexes.

Comment: Tried that but I m getting syntax error. I did SELECT EXTRACT(WEEK FROM TIMESTAMP bf.create_date) from my_table. Am I wrong in syntax?

Comment: The `TIMESTAMP` part is required for timestamp literals. Leave it out when extracting from a table column.

Comment: We can help better if you add your existing postgres code.

Comment: Thanks Alastor, dhke for your replies. I got it working the way dhke suggested. It was just a syntax issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the revenue by week, you'll need to group and aggregate:

`select extract (week from create_date) as week, sum(revenue) from table group by week`